# What does 1: mean in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, riscv

I was reading the source code of RISC-V test pattern.
And there is a macro define in riscv-test.h,

I want to know what does `1:` means in this code:

```
#define RVTEST_CODE_BEGIN                                               \
        .section .text.init;                                            \
        .align  6;                                                      \
        .weak stvec_handler;                                            \
        .weak mtvec_handler;                                            \
        .globl _start;                                                  \
_start:                                                                 \
        /* reset vector */                                              \
        j reset_vector;                                                 \
        .align 2;                                                       \
trap_vector:                                                            \
        /* test whether the test came from pass/fail */                 \
        csrr t5, mcause;                                                \
        li t6, CAUSE_USER_ECALL;                                        \
        beq t5, t6, write_tohost;                                       \
        li t6, CAUSE_SUPERVISOR_ECALL;                                  \
        beq t5, t6, write_tohost;                                       \
        li t6, CAUSE_MACHINE_ECALL;                                     \
        beq t5, t6, write_tohost;                                       \
        /* if an mtvec_handler is defined, jump to it */                \
        la t5, mtvec_handler;                                           \
        beqz t5, 1f;                                                    \
        jr t5;                                                          \
        /* was it an interrupt or an exception? */                      \
  1:    csrr t5, mcause;                                                \
        bgez t5, handle_exception;                                      \
        INTERRUPT_HANDLER;                                            \
```

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote any asm code, but 1: sure looks like a label to me.

Comment: Specifically it is a local label. You can read more about them here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/Symbol-Names.html#Symbol-Names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `1:` is a local symbol name; it's just a label. From the [`gas` manual](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC46):

> **Local Symbol Names**
>
> Local symbols help compilers and programmers use names temporarily.
>   They create symbols which are guaranteed to be unique over the entire
>   scope of the input source code and which can be referred to by a
>   simple notation. To define a local symbol, write a label of the form
>   N: (where N represents any positive integer). To refer to the most
>   recent previous definition of that symbol write Nb, using the same
>   number as when you defined the label. To refer to the next definition
>   of a local label, write Nf - The b stands for "backwards" and the f
>   stands for "forwards".
>
> There is no restriction on how you can use these labels, and you can
>   reuse them as well. So it is possible to repeatedly define the same
>   local label (using the same number N), although you can only refer to
>   the most recently defined local label of that number (for a backwards
>   reference) or the next definition of a specific local label for a
>   forward reference. It is also worth noting that the first 10 local
>   labels (0:...9:) are implemented in a slightly more efficient manner
>   than the others.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ```
> 1:        jra 1f 
> 2:        jra 1b 
> 1:        jra 2f 
> 2:        jra 1b
> ```
>
> Which is the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> label_1:  jra label_3 
> label_2:  jra label_1 
> label_3:  jra label_4
> label_4:  jra label_3
> ```
>
> Local symbol names are only a notational device.
>   They are immediately transformed into more conventional symbol names
>   before the assembler uses them. ...

In your example that label is referenced a few instructions prior:

```
beqz t5, 1f;
```

The `1f` there means "the next label named 1" and just jumps to that `1:`.

It's a convenient way to define and reference local labels without having to think up unique names everywhere.

Here's [another example](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests/blob/master/isa/macros/scalar/test_macros.h#L370):

```
#define TEST_JR_SRC1_BYPASS( testnum, nop_cycles, inst ) \
test_ ## testnum: \
    li  TESTNUM, testnum; \
    li  x4, 0; \
1:  la  x6, 2f; \
    TEST_INSERT_NOPS_ ## nop_cycles \
    inst x6; \
    bne x0, TESTNUM, fail; \
2:  addi  x4, x4, 1; \
    li  x5, 2; \
    bne x4, x5, 1b \
```

There we see the labels being referenced as `2f`, `1b`, etc.